# TSQL CTE: How to avoid circular traversal?

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression

I have written a very simple CTE expression that retrieves a list of all groups of which a user is a member.

The rules goes like this, a user can be in multiple groups, and groups can be nested so that a group can be a member of another group, and furthermore, groups can be mutual member of another, so Group A is a member of Group B and Group B is also a member of Group A.

My CTE goes like this and obviously it yields infinite recursion:

```
            ;WITH GetMembershipInfo(entityId) AS( -- entity can be a user or group
                SELECT k.ID as entityId FROM entities k WHERE k.id = @userId
                UNION ALL
                SELECT k.id FROM entities k 
                JOIN Xrelationships kc on kc.entityId = k.entityId
                JOIN GetMembershipInfo m on m.entityId = kc.ChildID
            )
```

I can't find an easy solution to back-track those groups that I have already recorded.

I was thinking of using an additional varchar parameter in the CTE to record a list of all groups that I have visited, but using varchar is just too crude, isn't it?

Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you sure it is recursing forever? The server default is 100 iterations. Try reading up on the `MAXRECURSION` hint on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

Comment: First worry about efficacy, *then* worry about crudeness, if time allows :)

Comment: it doesn't recurse forever because it throws an error after 100 recursive calls. Forgive my wording.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to accumulate a sentinel string within your recursion. In the following example I have a circular relationship from A,B,C,D, and then back to A, and I avoid a loop with the sentinel string:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(Parent CHAR(1), Child CHAR(1));

INSERT @MyTable VALUES('A', 'B');
INSERT @MyTable VALUES('B', 'C');
INSERT @MyTable VALUES('C', 'D');
INSERT @MyTable VALUES('D', 'A');

; WITH CTE (Parent, Child, Sentinel) AS (
    SELECT  Parent, Child, Sentinel = CAST(Parent AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM    @MyTable
    WHERE   Parent = 'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  CTE.Child, t.Child, Sentinel + '|' + CTE.Child
    FROM    CTE
    JOIN    @MyTable t ON t.Parent = CTE.Child
    WHERE   CHARINDEX(CTE.Child,Sentinel)=0
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

Result:

```
Parent Child Sentinel
------ ----- --------
A      B     A
B      C     A|B
C      D     A|B|C
D      A     A|B|C|D
```

Comment: I like your solution because it works. But is there a way to do this without a sentinel string? I feel it's clunky and duplicative that we have to add some kind of delimiter around each sentinel entry, say 

Sentinel = '<' + CAST(Parent AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '>'

Then we have to do the same in CharIndex() function, because without the delimiters there can be false positives. 
And what happens if the sentinel string gets so large that it exceeds the length of varchar(max)?

Comment: I'm glad to hear this works. It is a bit of a hack, and I honestly can't think of a "cleaner" way. But, keep in mind that the sentinel grows along each recursive branch independently, and so will only get as large as the max depth times each string, plus delimiter. VARCHAR(MAX) has a limit of 2 GB, while the max depth can be enlarged, if necessary, to a maximum of 32767. So, it is highly unlikely that you will ever overflow VARCHAR(MAX). Most recursion jobs might have a few thousand trees, but whose depths rarely exceed 5 or so. So, your sentinel strings will generally remain fairly small.

Comment: I think you have to build the sentinel string differently to avoid false positives in general case (when not using CHAR(1)). CHARINDEX might find `A` in `AB|C`, but not `<A>` in `<AB><C>`. Furthermore, if ID is allowed to contain < or >, you'd need to encode that properly too. Of course, none of this is a problem if you just keep using CHAR(1), but that's not a realistic case. Regardless, excellent idea and +1 from me!

Comment: In reference to what @BrankoDimitrijevic is saying, please see [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22453893/243373). It makes sure the identifiers in the sentinel are always delimited and verifies circular reference by looking up `delimiter + identifier + delimiter` in the sentinel.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a sentinel string, use a sentinel table variable.  Function will catch circular reference no matter how many hops the circle is, no issues with maximum length of nvarchar(max), easily modified for different data types or even multipart keys, and you can assign the function to a check constraint.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[AccountsCircular] (
    @AccountID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
RETURNS BIT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NextAccountID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL;
    DECLARE @Sentinel TABLE (
        ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    );

    INSERT INTO @Sentinel ([ID])
    VALUES (@AccountID);

    SET @NextAccountID = @AccountID;

    WHILE @NextAccountID IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SELECT @NextAccountID = [ParentAccountID]
        FROM [dbo].[Accounts]
        WHERE [AccountID] = @NextAccountID;

        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Sentinel WHERE ID = @NextAccountID) BEGIN
            RETURN 1;
        END;

        INSERT INTO @Sentinel ([ID])
        VALUES (@NextAccountID)
    END;

    RETURN 0;
END;
```