# SQL Server recursive query which is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, recursive-query

I have a table with three columns

```
unified_id
master_id
(the third column is a primary key identity)
```

For an id which could be in either id column, I want to find the set of ids.
For example, if the data looks like this

```
X001,X123
X002,X123
X123,X123
```

then starting from X001 I want to return with the set of `X001, X002 and X123`. Likewise I want the same set starting with any member.

We can assume that the set is composed of values in the unified_id column, that is we assume that there is always a row like the third one, relating the master id to itself.

When I have just one row the follow query hits maximum recursion level, so I frankly have no idea how to solve this with recursive queries.

```
2BM0000023, 1TE0000111
```

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE link_unified_id
 (unified_id         VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL,
  master_id   VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL
 );

insert into  link_unified_id values ('X001','X123');
insert into  link_unified_id values ('X002','X123');
insert into  link_unified_id values ('X003','X123');
insert into  link_unified_id values ('X123','X123');
insert into  link_unified_id values ('X999','X999');



with cte1 ( unified_id) as 
    (
        select 
            up1.unified_id 
        from 
            link_unified_id as up1 
        where 
            up1.unified_id =  'X001'

        union all

        select 
            up2.unified_id 
        from 
            link_unified_id as up2
        inner join 
            cte1 on up2.unified_id = cte1.unified_id
    )
    select *   
    from cte1 

/* hoping to see output like this:
X001
X002
X003
X123
*/
```

Comment: Please provide some example data to work with. Let it be table variables/temporary tables with inserts.

Comment: You can simply increase your maximum recursion level using `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)` if this is the issue. If the issue is that your `T-SQL` statement is not returning the desire output, you should display some sample data and what is the output you are looking for based on it.

Comment: edited as suggested...

Comment: maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452529/recursive-cte-in-presence-of-circular-references?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't get it but why not just join the master id from the selected item to the same table using that master id?

Something like this:

```
select lu1.unified_id
  from link_unified_id lu1,
       link_unified_id lu2
 where lu1.master_id = lu2.master_id
   and lu2.unified id = 'X001'
```

Comment: basically I want to build an undirected graph, so I want to find not just immediate links between two ids, but I want to follow that link to find others. So in the example, I start with X001 and I need to 'discover' that there is a connection with X002. It's sort of recursive in that X002 could have a different master ID that is in turn linked to other children. I have since seen that the SQL solutions for this are a bit hacky (I didn't realise I wanted an 'undirected graph' but now I know better).

Comment: Ah okay I see. I don't know about sql-server but on Oracle they have CONNECT BY which will do exactly what you want. Not sure if there's an equivalent of this for sql-server.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, my requirement is to build an "undirected graph" and then find paths in it (not sure what the terminology is), and this the solution to this in SQL is rather procedural (e.g. [Recursive CTE in presence of circular references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452529/recursive-cte-in-presence-of-circular-references?rq=1)). I have decided to actually build a graph by inserting these pairs via a Python library which seems more elegant than trying to do this in SQL.